# How do I access text inside an element while ignoring some text inside a tag adjacent to the text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is a good way to get the text out of a jQuery element when the text itself is adjacent to another element containing text?

In this example, I want to get at the text: 'Text I want' while ignoring the text in the adjacent child element:

```
<span>
   <a>Text I want to ignore</a> 
   Text I want
</span>
```

My solution was to get all the text in the `<span>` tag and then delete all the text in the `<a>` tag. This feels a little awkward so I'm wondering if there is a better way:

```
var all_the_text = $('span').text();
var the_text_i_dont_want = $('span').find('a').text();
var text_i_want = all_the_text.replace(the_text_i_dont_want, '');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to go to the text nodes for this:

```
var text_i_want = $("span").contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).text();​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UeBZq/

Comment: I always forget that text nodes' `nodeType === 3`, nicely done. May add that if OP wishes to trim the line breaks and extra spacing before/after the text he wants, you can use [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/UeBZq/2/).

Comment: This is Awesome! Just FYI: if you can guarantee that the textnode will always be the first element (before any child elms).. you can just reference it directly without the need to filter like so:
``var text_i_want = $("span").contents()[0]``
.. Or you can use ``.first()`` if you want to keep chaining jQuery methods.

Answer (score 6):

```
$("span")
    .clone()
    .children()
    .remove()
    .end()
    .text();
```

should do it

to give proper credit :) http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/

Answer (score 2):

remove a tag and get the span contents. [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/Gnwgb/)

```
<span>
   <a>Text I want to ignore</a> 
   Text I want
</span>​

var all_the_text = $('span').find('a').remove();
alert($('span').text());
```

Comment: Why `JSON.stringify`? you could use `$('span').text()`.

Comment: I dint care to refactor this as soon as it worked :) Cleaned it now!