# Ignore numbers in html tags with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I have a webfont I really want to use, however the font designer got lazy when creating the number characters. They are all different sizes compared to letter characters.

I'm trying to standardize them by applying a unique bit of css to each number character. This is only going to apply to h1 tags.

My technique in jquery is to search through text and apply a `<span class="font-fix-1">1</span>` for the number 1, `<span class="font-fix-2">2</span>` for the number 2 etc.

However, I don't want to target numbers which may be in html scripts.
For example, if I have the following h1:

```
<h1>This is a Heading with the number 20 in it and some <sup style="font-size:12px">annoying html</sup></h1>
```

I don't want the script to replace the number "2" in the `<sup>` tag, just the `<h1>` tag only.

Does anyone know how to recognize this with javascript?

My script I have so far is:

```
var h1_text = "";
jQuery("h1").each(function(){
    h1_text = jQuery(this).html();
    h1_text = h1_text.replace(/1/g, '<span class="font-fix-1">1</span>');
    jQuery(this).html(h1_text);
});
```

Comment: see answer: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147045/how-do-i-access-text-inside-an-element-while-ignoring-some-text-inside-a-tag-adj

Comment: The sizes of glyphs for digits is a font designer’s decision, and it often varies by font design. If you don’t like the decision, use another font.

Comment: ioseph, I checked this out, it's not the same functionality as i'm looking for. I need to be able to edit the node===3 text, then add it back to it's original string with original tags included.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

HTML

```
<span>
    <a>123456789</a> //number that you want to ignore
    Text I want //the text that you want
</span>
```

JavaScript

```
alert($("span").contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).text())
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly solve my problem. It allows me to see text that is not in tags, however I dont know how to edit this text and inject it back into string.